# Snowflake : List out all roles and their access level to each Database objects

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to get all the roles and their access to each database objects whether is it Read access or Write access

In Snowflake, I tried as below

`show roles`

`select * from table(RESULT_SCAN (LAST_QUERY_ID()));`

I'd like to show ALL grants for ALL roles in one table. My best guess would be to write a procedure that iterates through all the role names, executes the above code, and outputs the result to a table.

Is there a better way of doing this?

I also checked this view GRANTS_TO_ROLES , but not sure if this gives me all the roles for all the database

Comment: Just checking: do you mean just have access to the database object or do you mean have access to any object within the database? Obviously the DB contains schemas, tables, views, SPs, etc - all of which can have different permissions on them

Comment: access to any objects

Comment: What about roles that inherit from roles that have access to DB objects? As you say, you’ll need to write a SP to loop through all the objects you’re interested in

Comment: These three SPs may get you what you need, or close to it:  https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Capture-Snowflake-Users-Roles-and-Grants-Into-a-Table

Comment: @GregPavlik Thanks, Is not the view GRANTS_TO_ROLE data similar to one of the SPs data in the link you shared?